# Haskell function to recursively remove all occurrences of a given value in a list

Tags: haskell, recursion

For example, `myRemove 2 [2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4] = [1,3,1,3,4]`

Here's what I've done so far

```
myRemove :: a -> [b] ->[b]
myRemove a [] = []
myRemove (x:xs) =
    | a = x = myRemove - x
    | otherwise myRemove a xs
```

Comment: This is not a question. — I suggest you read http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards

Comment: `xs` is already the list you seem to assume `myRemove  - x` will produce.

Answer (score 3):

so many errors and typos, probable read little more about the language!

I guess that's what you're trying to do

```
myRemove :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
myRemove a [] = []
myRemove a (x:xs) | a==x      = myRemove a xs
                  | otherwise = x:(myRemove a xs)
```

when run with the input

```
> myRemove 2 [2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4]
[1,3,1,3,4]
```